# Newly installed SSL not working on apache2 - Receiving 310 Error - Too many Redirects

Tags: mod-rewrite, ssl, apache2

Disclaimer - I'm a total newb when it comes to this.  Inherited this issue.

I just installed the SSL certificate to our website.  Install seems to have gone fine.  Whenever I try to access a page via https I receive a 310 - Too many redirects error.  I suspect this has something to do with how my virtual host is setup but I don't know enough about what I am looking at.

Here is the code from the SSL virtual host

```
     <VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/file.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/file.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/path/file.crt"
    ServerAdmin admins@email.com
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/www
    <Directory /var/www/domain.com/www>
            SSLRequireSSL
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^labs$ http://www.mdlabtests.com/ [L]
        RewriteRule ^imaging$ http://prepaidimaging.com/ [L]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ /index.php?aid=$1 [L]
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /path/file.log
    TransferLog /path/file.log
    LogLevel warn
    Alias /comp /var/www/domain.com/www/comp.php
    <Location /card>
        DirectoryIndex create_card.php
    </Location>
    php_admin_value session.cookie_domain "domain.com"
    php_admin_flag session.cookie_secure off
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/domain.com/:/var/www/sub_dir/cg/:/usr/share/php/"
    php_value include_path ".:/var/www/domain.com/includes:/usr/share/php"
    php_admin_flag  file_uploads off
```

The page I am trying to access is https://domain.com/enrollment.php

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the php files doing any redirecting?

Comment: Hey Jon, you nailed it.  There was a html base code that sneaked in there that had it http instead of the https.  Kills me I was looking in the wrong place the whole time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or do you have an .htaccess file lurking on your filesystem?

Comment: I thought about that too, ended up being an html base at the top of my file that was causing the issue.  Thanks for the reply!